# Endless thread execution time difference

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, java-threads

I am trying to create a camera service which should continuously records.
 I could achive this by now. I save video files 1 hour long, and I create another one.

```
  public void run() {
        if(!SDCard.getInstance(mContext).isAvailable()){
            Log.e(TAG,"SD CARD IS NOT AVAILABLE");
            return;
        }
        createSurfaceCallback();
        while (true){
            if(surfaceExist){
                try{
                    boolean prepared = start();
                    if(prepared) {
                        mMediaRecorder.start();
                        recording = true;
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60*60);
                        failureCount = 0;
                    }else {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        recording = false;
                        failureCount ++;

                    }
                    destroy();
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    failureCount++;
                    recording = false;
                }
            }else{
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(200);//waits surface the created
                }catch (Exception ex){

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

So far my code runs perfectly in 3 days but my problem is there is a time difference between videos. For example,

1. Video : 11-04-48:258 - 12-04-48:258 (Time difference is none)
2. Video : 12-04-49:160 - 13-04-49:010 (First and second video has 900 ms time difference and shorter video)
3. Video : 13-04-52:078 - 14-04-51:976 (Second and third video has almost 3 seecond time difference and shorter video)

Why I am reaching this conclusion? What occurs the time difference in this ?

1. Thread scheduling problem from OS level.
2. Media recorder problem(might be buffering or restarting)
3. My code occurs this in some way.

These options I thing might be the reason of this problem but I am not sure. Can I decrease time difference and how ?

```
 private void destroy(){
        try {
            recording = false;
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It takes a while to save the files, of course there's a delay. Start a new thread to save the file and record on the main thread, use a second recorder as a buffer to save to the file system from

Comment: I only set output file path to media recorder. I do not use a buffer or anything. It is just my opinion my friend

Comment: I know, I suggested you to add a buffer. Writing the file to storage is why there's a delay

Comment: How could I add media recorder a different buffer? Could you send me samples?

Comment: I commented this because it could be an answer but I don't have the knowledge for this to be a full answer. use a second MediaRecorder to use as a write buffer and use a second thread for saving, use the main thread (not UI thread) for recording. No delays when you don't waste time writing to storage on the smae thread as recording